Creating Tables in Dynamo DB using Visual Studio
I tried creating a table in Dynamo DB using Python Visual Studio, but I have been getting this error message:
"An error occurred (IncompleteSignatureException) when calling the CreateTable operation: 'AWS' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXXX AWS Secret Access Key [None]:XXX
Please can someone help me with how to navigate through this error.
I have tried disabling my AWS users account, and also enabling console access, but none worked.
It seems I have to add a key to my code, but I dont know how to go about it.

I believe you have just shared your private AWS credentials with the world. I recommend you change them as soon as possible.

@Chinedu, just edited your question and removed the AWS credentials. Please be more careful about posting sensitive data.

Note that removing credentials from this question is not enough. You've leaked theme online and they are forever compromised. Invalidate them and generate new ones.
